# Remove XTickLabels partly but not Marks (matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want a plot with marks for every number, but label only every tenth mark.
I tried to do it like this:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:1:100);
set(gca, 'XTicklabel', [0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100]);
```

But this way it labels every mark, and it's not possible to read anything. I also tried to do this (delete all labels and than add only several):

```
set(gca, 'XTicklabel', []);
set(gca, 'XTicklabel', [0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100]);
```

but didn't work either. Any Suggestions how to solve this? I'm using Matlab R2014a.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried padding between your numbers with empty strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use empty labels when you don't want to display them

```
% Set up ticks and labels
ticks = 0:1:100;
labels = num2cell(ticks);
% Remove all but every 10th label
labels(mod(ticks,10)~=0) = {''};
% Set
set(gca, 'XTick', ticks);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', labels);
```

Example using `plot(1:100,1:100)` then the above code

[image: plot]